# Mootools selector trouble

Tags: javascript, mootools, css-selectors

I have this html:

```
    <div id="link-thumbs-list">
<img src="image.php?f=http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif&amp;h=72&amp;w=128" />
<img src="image.php?f=http://www.jetphotos.net/logo-nb.jpg&amp;h=72&amp;w=128" />
<img src="image.php?f=http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif&amp;h=72&amp;w=128" />
</div>
```

I need to select f= (file url) into src attribute of each imgs..
How can I do?? Thanksss

Comment: so for instance the end result for the first `<img>` would be `<img src='http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif&amp;h=72&amp;w=128' />` ?

Comment: NO, this: <code>http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$$("#link-thumbs-list img").each(function(elem) {
    var m = elem.get("src").match(/f=([^&]*)&/);
    if (m && m[1]) {
        elem.set("src", m[1]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

simply this:

```
var urls = document.getElements("#link-thumbs-list img").get("src").map(function(el) {
    return el.replace("image.php?f=", "").split("&")[0];
});

console.log(urls);
```

outputs:

```
["http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif", "http://www.jetphotos.net/logo-nb.jpg", "http://www.jetphotos.net/trans.gif"]
```